# UCI C API - How to set multiple options by running a single program only once

Tags: c, openwrt

I want to set multiple options at the same time using UCI C API.

I tried using below code but this sets only one option at a time.
But how to set multiple options and sections at the same time?

```
#include <uci.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uci_context* ctx = uci_alloc_context();

    if (!ctx) {
        printf("failed to alloc uci ctx\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uci_ptr config;
    char section_name[] = "your_package.your_section";

    if (uci_lookup_ptr(ctx, &config, section_name, true) != UCI_OK || !config.s) {
        printf("failed to find the specified section\n");
        return 1;
    }

    config.option = "new_option_name";
    config.value = "new_option_value";

    if (uci_set(ctx, &config) != UCI_OK) {
        printf("failed to set new option\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (uci_commit(ctx, &config.p, false) != UCI_OK) {
        printf("failed to commit changes\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you can do multiple uci_sets before the uci_commit?

Comment: Just repeat the code that sets up config.option and config.value then calls uci_set? e.g. `config.option = "new_option_1"; config.value = "new_value_1"; uci_set(ctx, &config); config.option = "new_option_2"; config.value = "new_value_2"; uci_set(ctx, &config);` (although keep the error handling you've got.) And then `uci_commit(ctx, &config.p, false);`

Comment: How can I make is user input program, so that no hard-coded values are used?

Comment: Basically, what you should be doing is operating not on pointers to options but package or sections as a whole. Examples are available if you look for "uci_sections" or "uci_package". Random link from drivers (please note that this can get outdated): https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/firewall3/utils.c#L405 (results for uci_package: https://lxr.openwrt.org/ident?i=uci_package)